# Async Image Download Function Swift - Some images dont return

Tags: swift

For some reason this function returns valid images for most, but then for some it just returns nothing. It shows data being exchanged but the images aren't being returned properly. Can someone help me improve this function some how to solve this issue.

```
    func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in
        var data: NSData? = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData

        if let goodData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: goodData)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            })
            return
        }

        var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                return
            }

            if data != nil {
                println(data)
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: urlString)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                })
                return
            }

        })
        downloadTask.resume()
    })
}
```

This is the whole class I am using, it has the Authors credits as well.

```
//
//  ImageLoader.swift
//  extension
//
//  Created by Nate Lyman on 7/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NateLyman.com. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import Foundation


class ImageLoader {

    var cache = NSCache()

    class var sharedLoader : ImageLoader {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in
            var data: NSData? = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData

            if let goodData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: goodData)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                })
                return
            }

            var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    println(error)
                    completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                    return
                }

                if data != nil {
                    println(data)
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: urlString)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                        completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                    })
                    return
                }

            })
            downloadTask.resume()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `self.cache` in different threads: `dispatch_async` vs `dataTaskWithURL`.

Don't re-invent the wheel, use good tested library for such kind of things

> https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Downloading images and storing them in cache is surprisingly not trivial programming task on iOS.

Also, you can use Objective-C library from the same author

> https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

It has useful category for UIImageView for downloading images directly in your UI controls (and storing them in system and memory cache).

Comment: If this is a `NSCache`, then accessing it from multiple threads is fine. As the docs say, "You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different threads without having to lock the cache yourself."

Comment: @Rob Ok, I'll update answer if Austin says what he means in self.cache

Comment: I personally didn't write this function, I was looking for Async Swift Image solutions and managed to find this one. It is using NSCache as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why to work so hard. There are many ways to do the same in less code.

```
func downloadImage(url: NSURL, handler: ((image: UIImage, error: NSError!) -> Void)) {
        var imageRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest,
            queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            completionHandler:{response, data, error in
                handler(image: UIImage(data: data)!, error: error)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that you should probably consider using a well-established framework such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If you want to remedy this, you should improve the error logging. I'd also suggest checking the HTTP status code:

```
func imageForUrl(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {
    if let data = self.cache.objectForKey(urlString) as? NSData {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            }
        }
        return
    }

    let downloadTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) { data, response, error in

        // report basic networking errors

        if data == nil {
            println("\(urlString) error \(error)")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
            }
            return
        }

        // report HTTP errors

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            if statusCode != 200 {
                println("\(urlString): statusCode = \(statusCode)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                }
                return
            }
        }

        // no HTTP error, let's try to get image

        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            self.cache.setObject(data, forKey: urlString)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
            }
        } else {
            println("\(urlString) found in cache, but not valid image")  // should never get here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
            }
        }
    }

    downloadTask.resume()
}
```